# Cant randomize Arrays in Swift with Int.random(in: x...y)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using earlier version of xcode (8.2.1) , I didnt succeed to update xcode from the app store.

any way it doesnt allow me to do randomize me arras elements ( which are cube picture for a roll dice app )

```
diceImageView.image  = [photo1...to..photo6 [Int.random(in: 0...5)]
```

the `.random` after `Int` just doesn't exist. I dont know what an alternative to use most of the stuff i've seached for they are more advanced or dont work\dont understand it,
 also tried `arc4random_uniform` unit32 and shuffle and such but it doesn't work.

can someone explain me how to randomize it?

Comment: You should update ASAP. Till then, you can use `arc4rand`

Comment: Instead of `Int.random(in: 0...5)`, you could use `Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(6)))`

Comment: The duped-answer includes solutions going back to Swift 1.2, so one of them should work for you. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Once you update Xcode you can just use the shuffle method like so `array.shuffle()`. The `shuffle()` method randomly reorders the elements of an array by passing in the system's default random generator and is O(n) complexity. I posted a screenshot below. [image]

Comment: Please post your code not as a screenshot, but include it properly formatted in your answer.